# Using PHP/cURL to query Azure Cognitive Services - Web Search API v5

Tags: php, api, azure, search, curl

am hoping someone can help me stop banging my head against a brick wall by pointing out where I am going wrong here.

I am attempting to use the Cognitive Services Search API v5 using PHP and cURL.  I have also tried using the PHP code example in the API documentation (found at: https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/bing-web-search-api/documentation) and still get the same problem: a 404 error.

Using the following PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=bill+gates&count=10&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safesearch=Moderate");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: XXXXXXXXXX"));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$reporting = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

I get the following report vars returned:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=bill+gates&count=10&offset=0&mkt=en-us&safesearch=Moderate
    [content_type] => application/json
    [http_code] => 404
    [header_size] => 123
    [request_size] => 205
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.276298
    [namelookup_time] => 0.153477
    [connect_time] => 0.177758
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.252367
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.276209
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 104.45.90.247
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 149.210.219.109
    [local_port] => 33405
)
```

I have tried the same code on a couple of different servers, and have the same problem.  I have also tried using cURl in a terminal successfully in order to make sure i had been using the correct subscription key.

Can anyone point out for me where I am going wrong, please?

cheers, Craig

Comment: I have built a PHP client for Azure Face REST API – https://github.com/darmen/php-azure-face-api-client – just in case if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The Endpoint of Cognitive Services Search API v5 is in https portal which requires to verify the SSL certificate.

If you use the code `$error= curl_error($ch);`, output the variable `$error`, you will get the error message `"SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"`.

The fast fix solution is to bypass the SSL certificate. Please try to add the sentence in your code snippet.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Apols for delay, but thanks for your advice - unfortunately it didn't make the query work.  However, changing the query from the dummy one supplied in the documentation (to search for something other than "Bill Gates") to search for something else instead DID work fine.